# Cannot resolve symbol 'create'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alarms

I am currently working on my first real Android Studio application. It's an alarm clock that play a custom .mp3 or .mp4 created by myself. I am having trouble right now getting the sound file to play. Any help or perhaps a point in the direction of another thread would be greatly appreciated. Here is some of the code:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //this will update the UI with message
    AlarmActivity inst = AlarmActivity.instance();
    inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer.create(AlarmReciever.this, R.raw.customsound);
```

For some reason I am getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'create'" while tring to use the media player. Again I am as newbie as newbie gets so I apologize if it's is incredibly obvious.

Answer (score 5):

**Create** is a static method, hence you are not supposed to use `new` keyword. The correct way is:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmReciever.this, R.raw.customsound);
```

Comment: Hmm still giving me "cannot resolve method 'create( )"

Comment: Are you using the `new` keyword? Update your question with the new code attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 new MediaPlayer(AlarmReciever.this, R.raw.customsound);
```

or without the new keyword

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmReciever.this, R.raw.customsound);
```

Comment: Hmm still giving me "cannot resolve method 'create( )"